# Laravel Flash message won't show up after Artisan::call('route::cache') command

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-artisan

I have a controller function for updating the stock of product variants.

I use a service to set the product to inactive when the variants are all discontinued and stock has become 0. If the case the product is set inactive I use Artisan::call('route::cache') to recache the routes.

When I come back to my controller I flash some messages with the Laracasts Flash package. But on reload they won't show up. When I test all the logic but without the Artisan call the flash message appears as desired.

I think it has to do with the fact that this route::cache command will create a fresh app() in the background and the session is resetted or something.

How can I fix this issue so I can both use the route::cache and the flash messaging after redirect?

Here is some example code:

```
/**
     * @param Order $order
     */
    private function updateStock(
        Order $order
    ): void
    {
        if ($order->payment->method->value === PaymentMethod::Invoice &&
            (!in_array($order->status->value, [OrderStatus::Open, OrderStatus::Canceled]) ||
                $order->payment->status->value === PaymentStatus::Paid) &&
            $order->processed_at === null) {

            $paymentService = new PaymentService();
            $results = $paymentService->updateVariantStockAndActivity($order->orderLines);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                switch ($result['type']) {
                    case 'discontinued':
                        flash($result['name'] . ' is uitverkocht en uit assortiment gehaald.')->error();
                        break;
                    case 'stock':
                        flash($result['name'] . ' - geen voorraad (' . $result['stock'] . ')')->warning();
                        break;
                }
            }

            $order->processed_at = Carbon::now();
            $order->save();
        }
    }
```

And for the service:

```
/**
     * @param Collection $orderLines
     * @return array
     */
    public function updateVariantStockAndActivity(Collection $orderLines): array
    {
        $results = [];
        foreach ($orderLines as $line) {
            $variant = $line->variant()->with('product')->first();

            if ($variant === null) {
                continue;
            }

            $newStock = $variant->stock - $line->quantity;
            $variant->update(['stock' => $newStock]);

            if ($newStock <= 0 && $variant->discontinued) {
                $variant->update(['active' => false]);
                $productDiscontinued = $this->updateProductActivity($variant->product);

                if($productDiscontinued) {
                    $results[] = [
                        'type' => 'discontinued',
                        'name' => $variant->product->full_name,
                    ];
                }
            }

            if ($newStock < 0) {
                $results[] = [
                    'type' => 'stock',
                    'name' => $line->name,
                    'stock' => $newStock,
                ];
            }
        }

        return $results;
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     * @return bool
     */
    private function updateProductActivity(Product $product): bool
    {
        if ($product->variants()->where('active', true)->doesntExist()) {
            $product->update(['active' => false]);

            Artisan::call('route:cache');

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```